manipulate .sqlproj file with powershell to change name of files in certain directory
So I have a SQL project in my visual studio solution.
In it, I got various folders, one is for update scripts which aren't supposed to be built, but most of the others(in specific folder and subfolders) need to be build, sometimes I forget to change the setting from None to Build.
Was thinking of changing this with a PowerShell script. But I'm kind of a noob in PS atm.
Here is what I have so far to select the nodes, but so far, the list seems to be empty.
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'Cob.Vessel.Wages.Database.sqlproj'
$selection = $xml.SelectNodes("//Project//ItemGroup//None//SubType")
Write-Output $selection

I'm not expecting you to present me with the whole solution to my problem but would appreciate a fix to my current problem.
Sample of my project file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
   <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="Data Generation Plans\UnitTestData.dgen">
         <SubType>NotInBuild</SubType>
      </None>
      <None Include="Scripts\Move_es10appraisaldocs_to_seafarerappraisal.sql">
         <SubType>NotInBuild</SubType>
      </None>
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I can display the root node(Project), but that's it. No idea how to display child nodes.

Can you post a snippet of your .sqlproj file?

What is empty?  Can u output the the main node (outerxml)? If true can u access the project node? Keep on drilling deeper till u find the problem

Added snippet for .sqlproj file.

You can't really "rename" an XML node, but you can replace it with a new node that has the correct new tag name and all the same attributes and child nodes, like so:
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'Cob.Vessel.Wages.Database.sqlproj'
$selection = $xml.SelectNodes('//Project/ItemGroup/None')

foreach ($noneNode in $selection) {
  # create a new `<Build />` node
  $buildNode = $xml.CreateElement('Build')

  # copy attributes to new node from existing
  foreach ($attribute in $noneNode.Attributes) {
    [void]$buildNode.SetAttributeNode($attribute)
  }

  # copy child nodes to new node from existing
  foreach ($child in $noneNode.ChildNodes){
    [void]$buildNode.AppendChild($child)
  }

  # replace existing node with new node
  [void]$noneNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($noneNode, $buildNode)
}

# write back to disk
$xml.Save((Resolve-Path 'Cob.Vessel.Wages.Database_modified.sqlproj'))

